# How can I decode a Hill Cipher without a key?

Tags: hill-cipher

On my exam, we had to solve this problem:

> message matrix is: `[20, 19, 14; 17, 0 10]`
>   and the ciphertext matrix is: `[18, 15, 16; 3, 24, 24]`.
>   Find key matrix.

I couldn't solve this problem, because I tried to find key matrix by multiplying 
`[20, 19, 14; 17, 0 10]^-1` and `[18, 15, 16; 3, 24, 24]`, but I wasn't able to calculate `[20, 19, 14; 17, 0 10]^-1`, because it's not a square matrix.

How can I decode a Hill Cipher without a key?

Comment: There's a comma missing after the first `0`, and perhaps some other parts of the statement (as is, by an entropy argument, it seems plausible that several keys could match).